# Cytoscape.js sample code, need a full example to dynamic populate nodes and edges

Tags: jsp, nodes, populate, edges, cytoscape.js

I am a newbie to Cytoscape.js and try to dynamically populate nodes and edges using jsp. I couldn't find a full example code for my purpose. May someone post their sample code or point me the real online application? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Cytoscape.js uses JSON, so you can either embed it in your page using JSP or build a webservice that your JS can query.  This isn't specific to Cytoscape.js, so I'm sure you'll find generic JSP/SpringMVC examples that will apply.